# Inconsistent vertical spacing using section headers

Tags: spacing, sectioning

Last week I read a short paper on LaTeX and now I'm writing my first document. I've googled and fixed most problems but this one I haven't found any working answer to. It's for a math assignment and I just want to write lots of math with a few \text{} comments in each solution so my document looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\lhead{Fredrik \qquad 2/5-2015}
\rhead{Inlämningsuppgift 2}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{15.5pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{15.5pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\begin{document}
\section*{Uppgift 2.1}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& u(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
& u_{1}=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \quad
u_{2}=\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\
& \nabla u(1,1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}j, \quad
|\nabla u|=\sqrt{\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) ^2 + \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}=1 \\
& v(x,y)=x+y+2\sqrt{xy} \\
& v_{1}=1+\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{xy}}=1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{xy}}, \quad
v_{2}=1+\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{xy}}=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{xy}} \\
& \nabla v(1,1)=2i+2j, \quad
|\nabla v|=\sqrt{4+4}=2\sqrt{2} \\
& \text{Grader } \theta \text{ mellan \textbf{u} och \textbf{v}:} \\ 
& \theta = \arccos \frac{u\bullet v}{|u||v|} \\
& \theta = \arccos \left( \frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}}{2\sqrt{2}} \right)=\arccos \left(\frac{4}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} \right)=\arccos(1)=0
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}

\section*{Uppgift 2.2}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& r=a+b, \quad |r|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, \quad \nabla r=ai+bj \\
& u=\sin \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right), \quad u_{1}=\frac{a \cdot \cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right) }{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \quad u_{2}=\frac{b \cdot \cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right) }{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \\
& \nabla u=\frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\left(ai+bj \right) \\
& \frac{ai+bj}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\bullet \frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}(ai+bj)=\frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right)\cdot a^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right)\cdot b^2}{a^2+b^2}= \\
& \frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right)\cdot (a^2+b^2)}{a^2+b^2}= \cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right)=\cos (r)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\section*{Uppgift 2.3}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& z(x,y)=6x^2 y^3-6x^2-9y^2+1, \quad \nabla z=(12xy^3-12x, 18x^2 y^2-18y)\\
& \text{Letar efter nollställen}\\
& 12x(y^3-1)=0, \quad y=0, \quad x=0 \qquad \ \text{ger } (0,0)\\
& 18y(x^2y-1)=0, \quad y=0, \quad x=\pm 1 \quad \text{ger } (1,1) \text{ och } (-1,1)\\
& z_{xx}=12y^3-12, \quad z_{xy}=z_{yx}=36xy^2, \quad z_{yy}=36x^2y-8\\
& \mathcal{H}=
\begin{bmatrix}
z_{xx} & z_{xy}\\
z_{yx} & z_{yy}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
12y^3-12 & 36xy^2\\
36xy^2 & 36x^2 y-18
\end{bmatrix} \\
& (0,0): \mathcal{H} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-12 & 0\\
0 & -18
\end{bmatrix}
\quad det(\mathcal{H})=(-12)\cdot(-18)-0=126 \\
& \begin{rcases}
det(\mathcal{H}) & > 0\\
f_{xx} & < 0
\end{rcases}
\text{Maxpunkt} \\
& (1,1): \mathcal{H} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 36\\
36 & 18
\end{bmatrix}
\quad det(\mathcal{H})=0-36 \cdot 36=-1296 
&&\quad det(\mathcal{H}) < 0 \\
& (-1,1): \mathcal{H} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -36\\
-36 & 18
\end{bmatrix}
\quad det(\mathcal{H})=0-(-36) \cdot (-36)=-1296
&&\quad det(\mathcal{H}) < 0 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\section*{Uppgift 2.4}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& f(x,y)=2x+8y-x^2-4y^2-4, \quad \nabla f=(2-2x, 8-8y) \\
& (1,1): \quad
\begin{rcases}
f_{xx} & =-2 \\
det(\mathcal{H})& =16
\end{rcases}
\text{maxpunkt}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\section*{Uppgift 2.5}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& f(x,y)=\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4} \\
& 000\text{Första delen}000 \\
& f_1 = \frac{4x}{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}}, \quad
f_2 = \frac{6y}{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}}, \quad 
f_{12}=f_{21}=\frac{-2x6y}{\left( \sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4} \right)^2} \\
\\
& f_{11} = \frac{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}-\frac{2x\cdot 4x}{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}}}{\left( 2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4} \right)^2}, \quad
f_{22}= \frac{3\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}-\frac{3y\cdot 6y}{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}}}{\left( 2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4} \right)^2} \\ \\
& \text{Kollar värden för derivatorna i punkten $(0,0)$} \\
& f_1=\frac{0}{2}=0, \quad f_2=\frac{0}{2}=0, \quad f_{12}=0, \quad 
f_{11}=\frac{2\cdot 2-0}{4}=1, \quad f_{22}=\frac{3\cdot 2-0}{4}=\frac{3}{2} \\
& P_2(x,y)= f(a,b)+f_1(a,b)(x-a)+f_2(a,b)(y-b)+\frac{1}{2} \left( f_{11}(x-a)^2+f_{22}(y-b)^2+2f_{12}(x-a)(y-b)\right) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& P_2(x,y)=2+0x+0y+\frac{1}{2}(x-0)^2+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}(y-0)^2+\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\cdot0(x-0)(y-0)=2+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2 \\
& P_2(0,1;0,1)=2+\frac{1}{2}(0,1)^2+\frac{3}{4}(0,1)^2=2+\frac{1}{200}+\frac{3}{400}=\frac{805}{400}=2,0125 \\
& f(0,1;0,1)=\sqrt{2(0,1)^2+3(0,1)^2+4}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{100}+\frac{3}{100}+4}=\sqrt{\frac{405}{100}}=2,01246 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\section*{Uppgift 2.6}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& f(x,y)=2x+y, \quad g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-5=0 \\
& L(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)=2x+y+\lambda (x^2+y^2-5) \\
& \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=2+2x\lambda, \quad
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=1+2y\lambda, \quad
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}=x^2+y^2-5 \\
& \text{Söker efter nollställen genom att sätta derivatorna lika med 0} \\
& \begin{rcases} & \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}= 0=2(1+x\lambda) \Rightarrow \lambda=-\frac{1}{x}  \\
& \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=0=1+2y\lambda \Rightarrow \lambda =-\frac{1}{2y} 
\end{rcases} \Rightarrow
-\frac{1}{x}=-\frac{1}{2y} \Rightarrow 2y=x \Rightarrow y=\frac{x}{2} \\
& \text{Sätter in resultatet i $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}=0$} \\
& 0=y^2+x^2-5 \Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{4}+x^2-5=0 \Rightarrow 0=5x^2-20 \Rightarrow 
4=x^2 \Rightarrow x=\pm 2 \\
& \text{Det ger} \\
& y=\frac{\pm2}{2}=\pm1 \text{ och } \lambda=\pm \frac{1}{2} \\
& \text{Ur det får vi punkterna $(2,1)$ och $(-2,-1)$ vilket ger} \\
& f(2,1)=4+1=5 \quad \text{och} \quad f(-2,-1)=-4-1=-5 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

This gives me an output where the spacing above and below the section headings differ (they indent differently too but that's not as important):

[image: part of pdf output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: LaTeX is working hard to keep sections with the following material but it has not got much to work on here - hence it stretches in the "least bad" place.  You can either add more text - or you can use something other than `\section` for the headings.   Also search for questions here about `\raggedbottom`...

Comment: Please fix the question so that the posted code matches the posted image.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get how to add code so did 4 spaces manually on each row. Now all code is there.

Comment: the `split` sub-environment is always handled as an unbreakable box.  to get rid of that, replace `equation*` by `align*`, remove `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}`, and insert `\allowdisplaybreaks` in your preamble.  since you have begun every display line with `&`, that will keep every line flush left.  you will still have many problems with lines too long.  (this is a comment and not an answer because i am having problems with the encoding, so can't reproduce the example without (irrelevant) errors.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Much better, got rid of the worst bits. Now I've got something to hand in. Thank you!

Comment: as @Thruston commented you should add `\raggedbottom` (my earlier comment that that was the default for `article` does not apply for `twoside` option.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I might have screwed it up but I've tried to add raggedbottom and I fail to see any difference.

Comment: `\raggedbottom` in the preamble makes the spaces go for me (although there are multiple errors from undefined characters when I run your example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. I slightly simplified your code with the `geometry` package and improved the formatting of decimal numbers with `siunitx`

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}%
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, headheight=14pt, hmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\lhead{Fredrik \qquad 2/5-2015}
\rhead{Inlämningsuppgift 2}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-decimal-markers={,},output-decimal-marker={,}}
\raggedbottom
\allowdisplaybreaks


\begin{document}

\section*{Uppgift 2.1}

\vskip-\abovedisplayskip
\begin{align*}
    & u(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
    & u_{1}=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \quad
  u_{2}=\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\
    & \nabla u(1,1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}j, \quad
  |\nabla u|=\sqrt{\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) ^2 + \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}=1 \\
    & v(x,y)=x+y+2\sqrt{xy} \\
    & v_{1}=1+\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{xy}}=1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{xy}}, \quad
  v_{2}=1+\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{xy}}=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{xy}} \\
    & \nabla v(1,1)=2i+2j, \quad
  |\nabla v|=\sqrt{4+4}=2\sqrt{2} \\
    & \text{Grader } \theta \text{ mellan \textbf{u} och \textbf{v}:} \\
    & \theta = \arccos \frac{u\bullet v}{|u||v|} \\
    & \theta = \arccos \left( \frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}}{2\sqrt{2}} \right)=\arccos \left(\frac{4}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} \right)=\arccos(1)=0
\end{align*}

\section*{Uppgift 2.2}

\vskip-\abovedisplayskip
\begin{align*}
    & r=a+b, \quad |r|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, \quad \nabla r=ai+bj \\
    & u=\sin \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right), \quad u_{1}=\frac{a \cdot \cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right) }{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \quad u_{2}=\frac{b \cdot \cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right) }{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \\
    & \nabla u=\frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\left(ai+bj \right) \\
    & \frac{ai+bj}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\bullet \frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}(ai+bj)=\frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right) \cdot a^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right) \cdot b^2}{a^2+b^2} \\
    & \qquad = \frac{\cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right) \cdot (a^2+b^2)}{a^2+b^2}= \cos \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right)=\cos (r)
\end{align*}

\section*{Uppgift 2.3}

\vskip-\abovedisplayskip
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  & z(x,y)=6x^2 y^3-6x^2-9y^2+1, \quad \nabla z=(12xy^3-12x, 18x^2 y^2-18y)\\
  & \text{Letar efter nollställen}\\
  & 12x(y^3-1)=0, \quad y=0, \quad x=0 \qquad \ \text{ger } (0,0)\\
  & 18y(x^2y-1)=0, \quad y=0, \quad x=\pm 1 \quad \text{ger } (1,1) \text{ och } (-1,1)\\
  & z_{xx}=12y^3-12, \quad z_{xy}=z_{yx}=36xy^2, \quad z_{yy}=36x^2y-8\\
  & \mathcal{H}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
  z_{xx} & z_{xy}\\
  z_{yx} & z_{yy}
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  12y^3-12 & 36xy^2\\
  36xy^2 & 36x^2 y-18
  \end{bmatrix} \\
  & (0,0): \mathcal{H} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  -12 & 0\\
  0 & -18
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \det(\mathcal{H})=(-12) \cdot (-18)-0=126 \\
  & \begin{rcases}
  \det(\mathcal{H}) & > 0\\
  f_{xx} & < 0
  \end{rcases}
  \text{Maxpunkt} \\
  & (1,1): \mathcal{H} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 36\\
  36 & 18
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \det(\mathcal{H})=0-36 \cdot 36=-1296
    & & \det(\mathcal{H}) < 0 \\
  & (-1,1): \mathcal{H} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -36\\
  -36 & 18
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad \det(\mathcal{H})=0-(-36) \cdot (-36)=-1296
    & \enspace & \det(\mathcal{H}) < 0
\end{alignat*}

\section*{Uppgift 2.4}

\vskip-\abovedisplayskip
\begin{align*}
                    & f(x,y)=2x+8y-x^2-4y^2-4, \quad \nabla f=(2-2x, 8-8y) \\
                    & (1,1): \quad
  \begin{rcases}
  f_{xx} & =-2 \\
  \det(\mathcal{H}) & =16
  \end{rcases}
  \text{maxpunkt}
\end{align*}

\section*{Uppgift 2.5}

\vskip-\abovedisplayskip
\begin{align*}
  & f(x,y)=\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4} \\
  & 000\text{Första delen}000 \\
  & f_1 = \frac{4x}{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}}, \quad f_2 = \frac{6y}{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}}, \quad
  f_{12}=f_{21}=\frac{-2x6y}{\left( \sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4} \right)^2} \\
  \\
  & f_{11} = \frac{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}-\frac{2x \cdot 4x}{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}}}{\left( 2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4} \right)^2}, \quad
  f_{22}= \frac{3\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}-\frac{3y \cdot 6y}{2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4}}}{\left( 2\sqrt{2x^2+3y^2+4} \right)^2} \\ \\
  & \text{Kollar värden för derivatorna i punkten $(0,0)$} \\
  & f_1=\frac{0}{2}=0, \quad f_2=\frac{0}{2}=0, \quad f_{12}=0, \quad
  f_{11}=\frac{2 \cdot 2-0}{4}=1, \quad f_{22}=\frac{3 \cdot 2-0}{4}=\frac{3}{2} \\
    & \!\begin{aligned} P_2(x,y)= f(a,b) & +f_1(a,b)(x-a) +f_2(a,b)(y-b) \\
  & +\frac{1}{2} \left( f_{11}(x-a)^2+f_{22}(y-b)^2+2f_{12}(x-a)(y-b)\right)
  \end{aligned}\\[1ex]
    & \!\begin{aligned} P_2(x,y) & =2+0x+0y+\frac{1}{2}(x-0)^2+\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2}(y-0)^2+\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\cdot0(x-0)(y-0) \\
  & =2+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2 \end{aligned}\\
  & P_2(\num{0,1};\num{0,1})=2+\frac{1}{2}(\num{0,1})^2+\frac{3}{4}(\num{0,1})^2=2+\frac{1}{200}+\frac{3}{400}=\frac{805}{400}=\num{2,0125} \\
  & f(\num{0,1};\num{0,1})=\sqrt{2(0,1)^2+3(\num{0,1})^2+4}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{100}+\frac{3}{100}+4}=\sqrt{\frac{405}{100}}=\num{2,01246} \end{align*}

  \section*{Uppgift 2.6}%

  \vskip-\abovedisplayskip
  \begin{align*}
  & f(x,y)=2x+y, \quad g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-5=0 \\
  & L(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)=2x+y+\lambda (x^2+y^2-5) \\
  & \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=2+2x\lambda, \quad
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=1+2y\lambda, \quad
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}=x^2+y^2-5 \\
  & \text{Söker efter nollställen genom att sätta derivatorna lika med 0} \\
    & \begin{drcases} & \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}= 0=2(1+x\lambda) \Rightarrow \lambda=-\frac{1}{x} \\
  & \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=0=1+2y\lambda \Rightarrow \lambda =-\frac{1}{2y}
  \end{drcases} \Rightarrow
  -\frac{1}{x}=-\frac{1}{2y} \Rightarrow 2y=x \Rightarrow y=\frac{x}{2} \\
  & \text{Sätter in resultatet i $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}=0$} \\
  & 0=y^2+x^2-5 \Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{4}+x^2-5=0 \Rightarrow 0=5x^2-20 \Rightarrow
  4=x^2 \Rightarrow x=\pm 2 \\
  & \text{Det ger} \\
  & y=\frac{\pm2}{2}=\pm1 \text{ och } \lambda=\pm \frac{1}{2} \\
  & \text{Ur det får vi punkterna $(2,1)$ och $(-2,-1)$ vilket ger} \\
  & f(2,1)=4+1=5 \quad \text{och} \quad f(-2,-1)=-4-1=-5
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(unfortunately, i'm unable to provide a full example, as i'm having problems with the encoding.  but since the op is satisfied with his/her output, i'll give the salient details here.)

the `split` sub-environment, like *all* sub-environments,
is always handled as an unbreakable box.
to get rid of that limitation,

- replace `equation*` by `align*`,
- remove `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}`, and
- insert `\allowdisplaybreaks` in your preamble.

since you have begun every display line with `&`, that will keep
every line flush left.

you will still have many problems with lines that are wider than the
declared text width.  check carefully to make sure that nothing is lost
by running past the edge of the paper.

possibilities for breaking lines intelligently (and intelligibly) are
described in the documentation for `amsmath` and `mathtools`.